# In my Django project wanted to show specific data on bootstrap modal as per project grid clicking but data is not changing on modal

Tags: django, modal-dialog

```html
<div class="container software-showcase-trio">
               <div class="row">
                  {% for maritime_content in maritime_project_content %}
                  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                     <a href="#" class="text-decoration-none" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#maritime-software-modal">
                        <div class="software-block-trio" style="background-image:url({{media_url}}{{maritime_content.cover_image}});">
                           <div class="software-block-hover-trio">
                              <h1>{{maritime_content.title}}</h1>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </a>
                     <!-- Modal -->
                     <div class="modal fade" id="maritime-software-modal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
                           <div class="modal-content">
                              <div class="modal-header">
                                 <h6 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"></h6>
                                 <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                              </div>
                              <div class="modal-body maritime-software-modal-body">
                                 <div class="maritime-modal-title">
                                    <h1 class="fw-bold display-5">{{maritime_content.title}}</h1>
                                 </div>
                                 <img src="{{media_url}}{{maritime_content.cover_image}}" height="500" width="1000" alt="">
                                 <div class="maritime-fields-title">
                                    <div class="maritime-project-details">
                                       <h3 class="fw-bold">Project Details</h3>
                                       <p class="">{{maritime_content.project_details}}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="maritime-problem-details">
                                       <h3 class="fw-bold">Problem</h3>
                                       <p>{{maritime_content.problem_details}}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="maritime-solution-details">
                                       <h3 class="fw-bold">Solution</h3>
                                       <p>{{maritime_content.solution_details}}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="maritime-technology-list">
                                       <h3 class="fw-bold">Technologies</h3>
                                       <p>{{maritime_content.technology_list}}</p>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="modal-footer">
                                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <!-- modal -->
                  </div>
                  {% endfor %}
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
```

In My Django Project I'm displaying category based project grid, and while someone clicked to that specific project grid a modal will appear with specific project data. But the problem I'm getting similar data on every modal appearance.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCnyF.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSwfI.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXopE.png

Answer (score 0):

That's happening because Id of each modal is same in your template.

> According to the JavaScript's rules id of each element should be
> unique.

There are many ways to fix your problem but the short one is to put {{forloop.counter}} in the id.

```
<div class="container software-showcase-trio">
               <div class="row">
                  {% for maritime_content in maritime_project_content %}
                  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                     <a href="#" class="text-decoration-none" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#maritime-software-modal">
                        <div class="software-block-trio" style="background-image:url({{media_url}}{{maritime_content.cover_image}});">
                           <div class="software-block-hover-trio">
                              <h1>{{maritime_content.title}}</h1>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </a>
                     <!-- Modal -->
                     <div class="modal fade" id="maritime-software-modal{{forloop.counter}}" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
                           <div class="modal-content">
                              <div class="modal-header">
                                 <h6 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"></h6>
                                 <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                              </div>
                              <div class="modal-body maritime-software-modal-body">
                                 <div class="maritime-modal-title">
                                    <h1 class="fw-bold display-5">{{maritime_content.title}}</h1>
                                 </div>
                                 <img src="{{media_url}}{{maritime_content.cover_image}}" height="500" width="1000" alt="">
                                 <div class="maritime-fields-title">
                                    <div class="maritime-project-details">
                                       <h3 class="fw-bold">Project Details</h3>
                                       <p class="">{{maritime_content.project_details}}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="maritime-problem-details">
                                       <h3 class="fw-bold">Problem</h3>
                                       <p>{{maritime_content.problem_details}}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="maritime-solution-details">
                                       <h3 class="fw-bold">Solution</h3>
                                       <p>{{maritime_content.solution_details}}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="maritime-technology-list">
                                       <h3 class="fw-bold">Technologies</h3>
                                       <p>{{maritime_content.technology_list}}</p>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="modal-footer">
                                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: after adding this id="maritime-software-modal{{forloop.counter}}" modal is not opening on  grid click